# Ways to book multiple flights

Tags: air-travel, bookings

I want to book a series of flights for example;

```
Prague, CZ       -> Split, Croatia (stay for 3 days)
Split, Croatia   -> Malta (stay for 3 days)
Malta            -> Lisbon, Portugal (stay for 3 days)
Lisbon, Portugal -> Prague, CZ
```

Is there a website that can easily help me book these flights where I don't have look for each individual flight, etc.?

Would you recommend I just book through a flight agency or is this something someone can book on their own?

Comment: It’s called multiple city/segment booking. You can do that on several websites including google flights.

Comment: Be aware though, it is not hard to look for individual flights, and it might save you 20+% on the roundtrip (because you have options to use unrelated airlines for different segments)

Comment: @David : yes, but he stated that he stays _three days_ at each location. There is little chance for any flight being over three days late.

Comment: @Aganju Thanks, I didn't read carefully enough. I'll delete my comment.

Answer (score 6):

You can do that through Google Flights in the following way:

[image: Round Trip]

Then choose Multi-City

[image: Multi-City]

Then add your desired flight segments. You can add more segments by clicking the "Add Flight" Button

[image: Add Flight]

Pressing search will guide you through the booking process. If possible, google will try to make everything in one booking. If not, it splits up the tickets and provides you the links for booking.

Comment: It's worth noting that many similar sites, if not most, offer the multiple city option.

Answer (score 3):

[Kiwi.com's "Nomad" tool](https://www.kiwi.com/ca/search?nomad=prague_cz~2018-10-24_2019-07-24~--%3B---~---~--%3BSPU~-~3-4%3BMLA~-~3-4%3BLIS~-~3-4) is useful if you're flexible on the order you visit your destinations. It will find the cheapest oder to visit the cities in.

[image: Kiwi.com Nomad search input fields]

[image: Kiwi.com Nomad search result]